# How to invoke the reset selection and select all in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How to reset the selected rows and select all rows on external button click? i am trying to resetSelection() but not working ...

```
jQuery("selectAll").click(function(){ 
  jQuery('.cbox').trigger('click'); 
});

jQuery("clear").click(function(){ 
  var grid = $("#list10"); 
  grid.resetSelection(); 
  $('#cb_my_grid').click(); 

  var ids = grid.getDataIDs(); 
  for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++ ) 
    grid.setSelection(ids[i], false); 
});
```

Comment: You should post the code example which not work.

Comment: jQuery("selectAll").click(function(){
     jQuery('.cbox').trigger('click');
     });

  jQuery("clear").click(function(){
   var grid = $("#list10");
     grid.resetSelection();
     $('#cb_my_grid').click();
     var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
     for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++ ) 
      grid.setSelection(ids[i], false);
   });

Comment: may be this link help https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/jqgrid-reset-row-selction-when-clicked-outside-or-lost-focus-or-onblur/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main reason why your code is not work is some syntax errors or wrong usage of [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You don't post your HTML code, so I suppose it look like following

```
<input id="selectAll" type="button" value="Select All" />
<input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear Selection" />
<table id="list10"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

The corresponding JavaSript code should be like following:

```
var grid = $("#list10");
$("#selectAll").click(function(){
    grid.jqGrid('resetSelection');
    var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
    for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++) {
        grid.jqGrid('setSelection',ids[i], true);
    }
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
    grid.jqGrid('resetSelection');
});
```

A working example you can see under the [Link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect1.htm) .

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still encountering this here is a solution the works for me:

```
//call resetSelection here

$('#cb_grid_id')
    .attr('checked','checked')
    .trigger('click')
    .attr('checked','checked');
```