# How to select all rows on a button click in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, selectall

I can I select all rows on button click ...lets say I have a button call Select All ..When I click on that button it needs to select all rows ....I did n't find any relevant documentation on JqGrid API ....

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't use http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect1.htm which I described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571324/how-to-invoke-the-reset-selection-and-select-all-in-jqgrid/3577559#3577559?

Comment: Are you the same Paul like http://stackoverflow.com/users/424687/paul?

Comment: Thanks!  Its working ..nopes I am not

Comment: You welcome! I am glad to hear, that I could helps two Paul!

Comment: Oleg how can I vote for this answer...this is really a simple and nice code..

Comment: Thank you for advice! I filled the information from the comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that [this example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect1.htm) which I described in [How to invoke the reset selection and select all in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571324/how-to-invoke-the-reset-selection-and-select-all-in-jqgrid/3577559#3577559) do what asked.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following Code

```
jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#toolbar_toppager',{caption:"Select All", onClickButton:function(){ 
         if($('.cbox').is(":checked")){ jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('resetSelection'); }else{$('.cbox').trigger('click').attr('checked', true);}
      } });
```

This seems to fix the issue with having to double click on the check boxes